# trouble displaying data from stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

My problem is that when the home page is loaded I want to return a function as the body of a scaffold that checks if a stream (groups, which is a query snapshot that has its state set by super.initState) is not equal to null, if groups is not equal to null, I wanted to display a list of cards that contains the group name and owner. If the group is equal to null i want to display one card that on tapped, will enable the user to create a group, So the page loads when the app starts and displays one card for group creation(when debugging) shortly after the page is re-rendered and when the groups stream object is passed to the conditional for some reason it is not equal to null, yet there is nothing to my knowledge that is in the query snapshot, after passing the condition for whatever reason snapshot.data.documents is called and I'm presented with "The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents". 
Here's my code, sorry if I over informed you I'm new to posting on stack.

```
  getUsersGroups() async{
var usr = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
return _firestore.collection('groups').where('members',arrayContains: usr.email).snapshots();}

@override
void initState() {
_dataService.getUsersGroups().then((results) {
  setState(() {
    groups = results; 
  });
});
super.initState();
}

groupCardList() {
if (groups != null){
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: groups,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, i){
          return new InkWell(
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0, bottom: 4.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(snapshot.data.documents[i].data['name'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),),
                        Spacer(),
                        Text(snapshot.data.documents[i].data['owner'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),),
```

getUsersGroups() is in a data_services.dart file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to setState() in initState():

Your getUserGroups should be something like:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUserGroups() {
    return _firestore.collection('groups').where('members',arrayContains: usr.email).snapshots();
}

// in your StatefulWidget:
Stream<QuerySnapshot> groups;

@override
void initState() {
     groups = _dataService.getUserGroups();
}
```

Now to your question. I believe that groups != null because the Object QuerySnapshot was created. You can check if groups has data in the StreamBuilder:

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: groups,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder { ... }
        }
        return (whatever you want to return when groups == null)
);
```

I hope that it helps :)